# winston http transport example

Tags: node.js, winston

I need a working example which post the logs on server using http transport. I'm able to use **file** transport and **console** transport to log message in file and on console. Same way I tried doing for **http** transport also, the source cod for winston clien looks something like this :

```
var winston = require('winston');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
  new (winston.transports.Console)(),
  new (winston.transports.Http)({ host: 'localhost', port:8080 })
]
  });

logger.log('info', 'Hello world');
```

While runnign this code I get error like :

```
D:\Balwant\Devlopment-Env\LoggingDemo\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\transports\http.js:52
req = (self.ssl ? https : http).request({
     ^
ReferenceError: self is not defined
at Http._request (D:\Balwant\Devlopment-    Env\LoggingDemo\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\transports\http.js:52:10)
at Http.log (D:\Balwant\Devlopment-Env\LoggingDemo\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\transports\http.js:109:8)
at emit (D:\Balwant\Devlopment-Env\LoggingDemo\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:175:17)
at D:\Balwant\Devlopment-Env\LoggingDemo\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:111:13
at Array.forEach (native)
at _each (D:\Balwant\Devlopment-Env\LoggingDemo\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:32:24)
at Object.async.each (D:\Balwant\Devlopment-Env\LoggingDemo\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:110:9)
at Logger.log (D:\Balwant\Devlopment-Env\LoggingDemo\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:203:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Balwant\Devlopment-Env\LoggingDemo\logger.js:10:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Since I'm new to node.js, I've no idea how to deal with it. I tried googling for solution but could not get any. 
Plese help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) and [winstond](https://github.com/flatiron/winstond) are different packages. You can check [this blog post](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/introducing-winstond/) about the difference.

You might also need to whip-up your own HTTP transport for winston (if you really want to use winston). So it can work with your specific endpoint protocol.

You can create your custom winston transport as specified [here](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#adding-custom-transports). Then you can use something like [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to send the log data to your HTTP endpoint.

Good luck.

### Web Transport

I don't believe `winston.transports.Http` exists but I think you're looking for this:

```
new winston.transports.Webhook({ 'host': 'localhost', 'port': 8080, 'path': '/collectdata' })
```

As shown in [this example](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/examples/webhook-post.js).

### Winstond

My mistake, [it does have](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#http-transport) `winston.transports.Http` but you'll need **winstond**.

You can check [this example](https://github.com/flatiron/winstond/blob/master/usage/sample.js) to use **winstond** as a http daemon. Then send your Http logs to it.

So this:

```
new winston.transports.Http({ host: 'localhost', port: 8080})
```

Should be pointing to a **winstond** daemon like:

```
var winstond = require('winstond');

var http = winstond.http.createServer({
  services: ['collect', 'query', 'stream'],
  port: 8080
});

http.add(winstond.transports.Console, {});
http.listen();
```

Comment: Thaks for reply. Can't I use something similar to File transport like new (winston.transports.Http) ({ host: 'localhost', port: 8080}) :

Comment: I dont believe there is a Http transport. See my updated answer.

Comment: Well, I'm not still clear how the log will be sent to server and displayed back to client. I've seen the above example but have no idea how to use it :(

Comment: Check-out winstons log querying. [here](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#querying-logs).

Comment: I tried the way you said, I've created winstond daemon which is running on port 8080, and other application which send http log to server. The code for that is : var winston = require('winston');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Http({ host: 'localhost', port: 8080})
  ]
});

logger.log('info', 'Hello, this is a raw logging event',   { 'foo': 'bar' }); But I'm getting error like : req = (self.ssl ? https : http).request({
         ^
ReferenceError: self is not defined...(and more) . Plese let me know whether I'm going wrong or right.

Comment: Seems like this reply is outdated unfortunately

Answer (score -6):

```
    var winston = require('winston');

    var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
      transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: false, timestamp: true }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: __dirname + '/debug.log', json: false })
      ],
      exceptionHandlers: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: false, timestamp: true }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: __dirname + '/exceptions.log', json: false })
      ],
      exitOnError: false
    });

    module.exports = logger;

add this line were ever u wanted to lg the error message
var logger = require('../../config/logger.js');
logger.info("the default logger with my tricked out transports is rockin this module");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - could you explain what you have changed?

Comment: this answer doesn't provide any information about the original question on sending logs over http

Comment: This doesn't provide any information regarding the winston HTTP transport